# XHR call using plain JavaScript

Tags: javascript, html, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I am having issue with XHR call made to GitHub domain from localhost.

Upon clicking on the button `Click to get User Profile with Ajax+JS`, a JS function `getUser()` gets called. Code works as expected, i.e., gets a particular GitHub user details(full name and avatar) and displays on the page.

```
## Code for "Click to get User Profile with Ajax+JS" button
<input type="button" value="Click to get User Profile with Ajax+JS" onclick="getUser()" id="jsBtn" />
```

BUT, when I call the same JS function on form submission using `submit` button (or return), it does not return the expected result i.e., user details.

```
## Code for "Submit" button
<form id="myForm" onsubmit="getUser()">
    #...
    <input type="submit"/>
</form>
```

Upon inspecting under `Network`, I see the difference in the way Request URL is formed in Request Headers Section:

```
## With GitHub username input as kirtithorat
## First Case With "Click to get User Profile with Ajax+JS" button
Request URL:https://api.github.com/users/kirtithorat

## Second Case With "submit" button
Request URL:http://localhost:3000/html_file_name?username=kirtithorat
```

Why the difference in behavior? The same JS function works for onclick but not for onsubmit.

**NOTE:**

1. I am looking for a **Pure JS** Solution. I know how to do it in
   jQuery.
2. I don't actually want the form to be submitted, only the
       `onSubmit` event should be triggered.

Here is my **[JSFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/znd3obLf/2/)**

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your second URL looks like the form submission, NOT the result of calling `getUser()` (the `getUser()` ajax call probably came right before the form submission).

If you don't want the form to actually submit (which it appears is how you want it) and only want your onSubmit handler to be called, then you need to make sure the default behavior of submitting the form is prevented.

You can block form submission by just adding a

```
return false;
```

to the end of your `getUser()` onsubmit handler function.

---

Or, you can block the form submission by passing the event into the `getUser()` function and using `e.preventDefault()`.

---

The other reason to block the form submission is that the page will reload with the results of the form submission and your javascript will not still be active to receive the results of the `getUser()` ajax call.  So, you must use one and only one of the Ajax call or the form submission (it looks like you just want the ajax call so you can prevent the form submission).

Comment: I would prefer `event.preventDefault()` to `return false;` for coding clarity.  Preventing the default submission is what you want to have happen, and though `return false` likely will accomplish this, it is a side effect rather than a directly intended effect.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks for the response. I used `return false` in my code but no luck. Its the same `Request URL:http://localhost:3000/html_file_name?username=kirtithorat`

Comment: @user1167442 - if this isn't working for you then you are not correctly blocking the submission of the form.  Your `getUser()` function isn't even capable of creating that URL (different domain, different URL) and that second URL exactly matches a form submission done via a GET.  So, the issue is how to correctly block the form submission.  The `getUser()` code in your jsFiddle does NOT have `return false` in either of the places the function returns.

Comment: @jfriend00 But then how does with onclick button event forms the perfect URL(different domain, different URL). I am still stumped on how to block form submission as you said.

Comment: @KirtiThorat - see http://jsfiddle.net/jfriend00/v6c6vv2r/2/ for blocking the form submission.  Note changes to both the `onsubmit()` in the HTML and to the `getUser()` function.

Comment: @jfriend00 Thanks a million. Unfortunately I can only give you one upvote. :)

Comment: @jfriend00.  I'm not saying yours wouldn't work; or won't;  I'm saying that since what you are actually doing is preventing the default action of a form submission, semantically it makes sense to use the JavaScript method designed to prevent default responses associated with events.